# error msgs after second loop attempt

Tags: java

I'm working on another assignment and am stuck. First off, I realize I probably won't get the results I want from this code, but at the moment I can't run the code to even see how close or far away I am. I'm sure I'm missing something simple and hope that something will pop out to someone here so I can move past this point. My mother tongue is English but I'm living in Sweden and trying to learn code in a Swedish class so I added //for translations.
Again, I am working with very basic code so am not looking for an easy hack, more of just some insight to where I have gone wrong. 
My assignment is to ask the user to enter 10 numbers, store those as an array. Then, offer the user 4 options to calculate those numbers and a 5th option to quit the program.
Here's what I have so far:

```
package inlämningsuppgift3;

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Inlämningsuppgift3 {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int nr;
    int antal = 0;
    int[] num = new int[10];
    int sum = 0;
    int min = 0;
    int max = 0;
    for (nr = 0; nr < 10; nr++) {
        System.out.println("Ange ett tal " + (nr+1) + " : ");

        int tal = input.nextInt();
        num[nr] = tal;
        if (nr == 0) { //first number
            min = tal;
            max = tal;
        }
        else { // All other numbers
            if (tal > max) { max = tal; }
            if (tal < min) { min = tal; }
        }

        sum = sum + tal;
    }
    {
        // What would you like to do?
        System.out.println("Välj vad du vill göra?");

        // Show largest number
        System.out.println("1: Visa storsta talet.");
        // Show smallest number
        System.out.println("2: Visa minsta talet.");
        // Show average
        System.out.println("3: Visa medeltalet.");
        // Show all numbers
        System.out.println("4: Visa alla inmatade tal.");
        // Quit
        System.out.println("5: Avsluta");
    }
    do {
        int k = input.nextInt();
        if (k == 1) {
            // Largest number is:
            System.out.println("Storsta talet är: " + max);
        }
        else if (k == 2) {
            // Smallest number is:
            System.out.println("Minsta talet är: " + min);
        }
        else if (k == 3) {
            // Average number is:
            System.out.println("Medeltalet är: " + sum/10);
        }
        else if (k == 4) {
            // All the entered numbers:
            System.out.println("Alla tal: " + num[10] + ", ");
        }
        else if (k==5) {
            // Goodbye
            System.out.println("Hej då!");
            break;
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Felaktigt, prova igen.");
            // Unrecognized, try again.
        }
        while (k<5);
    }
}
}
```

I'm getting error on the last 3 `}` and I'm not sure why. Are they in the wrong place? I've tried moving them around, I've tried deleting them (obviously, didn't help either) I tried changes to my {} placement above in the code and just haven't found a way around this error. Thank you in advance for any input!

Comment: Your `while (k < 5);` is outside of your loop. Move it down below the next `}`. Also it probably won't recognise `k` then, so move the declaration of `k`.

Comment: I suggest you reformat the code, it will be easier to spot the bug. Most IDE's support automatic formatting.

Comment: Thanks! I really thought I had done that, but must have missed it!

Comment: A few suggestions: You can use a `switch` statement instead of a bunch of if-else statements; `k` is not accessible, because you define it *inside* the `do` block, and you're using it in the `while` condition.

Comment: That's a great suggestion, and I will in the future. For now we are just learning if-else, and will be moving on to switches next week. I think the teacher wants us to realize how helpful switches will be after we have the basic if-else down pat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

java do-while syntax is:

```
do {
   // Statements
}while(Boolean_expression);
```

so, change it to:

```
    int k = 0;
    do {
        k = input.nextInt();
        if (k == 1) {
            System.out.println("Storsta talet är: " + max);
        } else if (k == 2) {
            System.out.println("Minsta talet är: " + min);
        } else if (k == 3) {
            System.out.println("Medeltalet är: " + sum / 10);
        } else if (k == 4) {
            System.out.println("Alla tal: " + num[10] + ", ");
        } else if (k == 5) {
            System.out.println("Hej då!");//good bye
            break;
        } else {
            System.out.println("Felaktigt, prova igen.");
        }
    } while (k < 5) ;
```

and after `while` line must be two `}` now.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you! Now I can work on getting option 4 to function correctly. It always surprises me how a simple fix for someone with experience can take me hours!

Answer (score 0):

**Hej Hej!**

I made the modifications I think like you asked to make it 'just about work'

```
package Dunno;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class NumberCollector { //No special characters in source files,
                               //Can get transformed during deployment

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int nr;
    int antal =0;
    int[] num = new int[10];
    int sum = 0;
    int min=0;
    int max=0;
    for (nr=0; nr<10; nr++)
    {
        System.out.println("Ange ett tal " + (nr+1) + " : ");

        int tal = input.nextInt();
        num[nr]=tal;
        if(nr == 0) //first number
        {
            min=tal;
            max=tal;
        }
        else //all other numbers
        {
            if(tal>max)max =tal;
            if(tal<min) min=tal;
        }

        sum = sum + tal;
    }

    System.out.println("Välj vad du vill göra?");
//what would you like to do?


    System.out.println("1: Visa storsta talet.");
//Show largest number
    System.out.println("2: Visa minsta talet.");
//show smallest number
    System.out.println("3: Visa medeltalet.");//show average
    System.out.println("4: Visa alla inmatade tal.");
//show all numbers
    System.out.println("5: Avsluta");//quit




        while (true) //Moved the stop condition to start of the loop makes it easier to read logically.
        {
            int k = input.nextInt();

            if (k==1)
            {
                System.out.println("Storsta talet är: " + max);
//largest number is:
            }
            else if (k==2)
            {
                System.out.println("Minsta talet är: " + min);
//smallest number is:
            }
            else if (k==3)
            {
                System.out.println("Medeltalet är: " + sum/10);
//average number is:
            }
            else if (k==4)
            {
                System.out.println("Alla tal: " + num[10] + ", ");
//all the entered numbers:
            }
            else if (k==5)
            {
                System.out.println("Hej då!");//good bye
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("Felaktigt, prova igen.");
//unrecognized, try again.
            }
};
}
}
```

I only had to move around some braces.
It seems to broadly do what you want? It throws an exception if you ask for result 4, I'll leave that to you :)

Maybe this will be a good starting point? Consider replacing the loop with a switch/case condition would be nicer to read and maintain?

Comment: Thank you! I need to practice more with my bracket placements! Such a small thing makes such a big difference!